# Occurance of a word in a matrix present in left to right, downwards or diagonal towards left(upward or downward)

Tags: javascript, c, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I have a input that defines the dimension of matrix, then 
I have a square matrix of that dimension containing random alphabets given as input, I have a input string i want to search the string in the matrix, i can search this string in **left to right horizontally**, **vertically downwards** or **diagonally towards left**(both upwards and downwards)

say for a given matrix

```
n = 3
A A K
A S K
A K K

  00 01 02
00 A  A  K 
10 A  S  K
20 A  K  K
```

and for a given string ASK i have to search all the occurrence of 'ASK'

The output will be **`4`** as there are four occurance of 'ASK'

2 are simple one : 01,11,21 and second : 10,11,12

But i cant understand how to match the string diagonally upwards or downwards towards left.
the 3rd : 02,11,20 and the 4th: 22,11,00

Comment: Do you want the sloution in python or in js?

Answer (score 0):

For diagonal search downward to left you should use loop similar to this,
supposing that it is related to rows, and j to columns, and 
both indices start with zero in top-left corner:

For diagonal search upward left rows should be decremented and columns incremented:

```
int i = n-1;
int j = 0;
while(i >=0 )
{
     //access element x[i][j] and store to a resulting string
   i--;
   j++;   
}
// compare resulting string to predefined string
```

For diagonal search upward to left rows and columns should be decremented :

```
int i = n-1;
int j = n-1;
while(i >= 0)
{
    //access element x[i][j] and store to a resulting string
   i--;
   j--;   
}
// compare resulting string to predefined string
```

Comment: Hello, I've got a question. Your answer is javascript, mine is python. Do you have an idea which language he wanted to have? I mean, the tags are both included.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I had "C" in mind when wrote my answer  :), had no idea what language OP prefer.I am supposing that the answer is readable for everybody who use  tagged languages - #c, #java-script and #python.  Actually, my intention was to offer  "algorithm-oriented" answer that explains how to address elements of matrix  in desired way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find all tuples that make up a combination so that the string can be read.

According to my opinion, it's easier when you assign every position of the grid a specific number, so in a 3x3 matrix it would be:

```
A H G    # A is 1; H is 2; G is 3; next line: C is 4; B is 5...
C B M
F U S
```

So making a universal solution to determine that numbers would be sorting them in a list (I don't know your input format, so I assume it's a list):

```
m = ['A', 'H', 'G', 'C', 'B', 'M', 'F', 'U', 'S']
```

Next, to find all tuples, we need to look at the example above.
In the positions of the list thats, `[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]`
and finnaly `[0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]`.

This is an algorithm to solve that:

```
def findTp(dimension):
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    lRes = []
    lR = range(0, dimension**2)
    for c in range(dimension**2):
        l1.append(lR[c:c+dimension])
    lRes.append(l1[::dimension])

    lR = []
    for i in range(dimension**2):
        lR.append(i)
    for i in range(dimension):
        lRes.append(lR[i::dimension])

    lR = []
    for i in range(dimension**2):
        lR.append(i)
    lRes.append(lR[::dimension+1])
    d = lR[dimension-1::dimension-1][:dimension]
    lRes.append(d)

    return lRes
```

Next, we will do some magic to extract the first list to `lRes`:

```
a = findTp(dimension)
b = a[1:]
c = a[0]
for i in c:
    b.append(i)
```

Now, we have the result stored in `b`.

Hope that helped.